# .NET Windows forms DataGridView Cell text disappears when added programatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a Windows forms application that includes a `DataGridView`. This `DataGridView` has 3 columns, all of which are simply text cells:

- `Timestamp`
- `Connection`
- `Message`

The issue I'm running into is that when I add a row (programmatically), I'm finding that the text disappears if it is too long. To be specific, if the text exceeds **4563** characters in length, then the text disappears.

I know that the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` class has a property call `MaxInputLength` that can limit the number of characters entered. But according the the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.maxinputlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it only affects text that is input manually by the user. I, however, am inputting this text programmatically.

Just to make sure though, I set this property very high but the disappearing text issue still arises when I pass the **4563** character limit.

One thing I have noticed is that the text is still there (i.e. the scroll bar along the bottom can still be scrolled as though the text is still there) but I cannot see the text itself. I can also edit the text.

I can add characters until the **4563** limit but as soon as I pass that, the text disappears. If I press backspace to return to exactly **4563** characters, the text reappears.

I am developing this using .NET 4.0, since I have to support Windows XP.

Comment: Do you have "WrapMode" set to true?

Comment: +1 for clear, thought out question and demonstration of some research. Are you doing any formatting or input restriction on the Cell level? This would have the potential to override any properties set at the Column level. Though this sounds like a display thing.

Comment: @glace Yes I am doing some formatting after adding the the row. Specifically, I am changing the font style of the row.

_logGridView.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular);

I've done some testing and it seems that changing the font is limiting the number of characters that can be input into the cell.

Comment: If I comment out the code I used to change the font, the text still disapears except at 5460 characters.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce what you say with a default, out of the box DataGridView (at least near or around the explicit numbers you mention). As you also said, it appears to be affected by the font size. There appears to be no reason for this to happen. Good question that deserves some more eyes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the short answer that will probably disappoint you: It's a reported bug and verified by Microsoft, closed as "Not important enough to fix". There may be more instances of it, but it's been known since at least 2011 [DataGridView control shows blank cell if large string is entered and column resized to max](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634750/datagridview-control-shows-blank-cell-if-large-string-is-entered-and-column-resized-to-max). The "workaround" is to just limit the size of the cells width, but for you that may not be satisfactory.

However, curiosity got the best of me so I started looking into it a little deeper; Here's the first observation worth mentioning:

[image]

If you look at the series of pictures, you'll notice I replicated your problem with the default font size/style and the specific number 5460. What's so special about 5460? Well, nothing in particular, except that as your character threshold crosses it the ContentBounds and Width of the column passes 32767. What's so special about 32767? Other than being the default `MaxInputLength` of a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, it's the upper limit of a signed short or Int16 (2^15-1). I highly doubt it's a coincidence the issue is occurring here, though not cause of anything to do with `MaxInputLength` per se. I'd be willing to bet you first noticed the issue at 4563 characters because your font size expanded the width to 32767 as well.

The next question, is why? I'm not really sure. I started following the rabbit hole and disassembled some of the .NET 4.0 DataGridView* libraries to find out. It's a pretty massive and complicated control, and I haven't been able to draw any definite conclusions, but one thing I found that's worth noting is the absolute maximum width a column can assume is 65536, the value of an UNsigned Int16 (2^16):

[image]

You see this check in a lot of private internal places when adding or resizing a column, and I tested it. The size won't go larger

This is ironic for two reasons. For one, using the default settings, you can only display 10922 characters (65536 / 6 pixels per character) in a column despite the editing input length being 32767 characters, and programmatically arbitrary.

Second, why would this issue start cropping up at exactly the max of the signed variant of the columns max width? Hmmmm. This is **totally** a guess, but I think somewhere along the line the max value for whatever renders the text was set as a regular short instead of an unsigned short... *or something along those lines*. I have my suspicions of the `PaintPrivate()` method in the implementation of `DataGridViewTextBoxCell()`, so if you're feeling frisky, maybe put a microscope to it. You'll need an IL disassembler to see this stuff that's not exposed publicly. Specifically, this part of the code I have suspicions of:

```
  if (text != null && (paint && !flag2 || computeContentBounds))
  {
    int y = cellStyle.WrapMode == DataGridViewTriState.True ? 1 : 2;
    rectangle3.Offset(0, y);
    // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
    // ISSUE: variable of a reference type
    Rectangle& local = @rectangle3;
    // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
    int width = (^local).Width;
    // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
    (^local).Width = width;
    rectangle3.Height -= y + 1;
    if (rectangle3.Width > 0 && rectangle3.Height > 0)
    {
      TextFormatFlags cellStyleAlignment = DataGridViewUtilities.ComputeTextFormatFlagsForCellStyleAlignment(this.DataGridView.RightToLeftInternal, cellStyle.Alignment, cellStyle.WrapMode);
      if (paint)
      {
        if (DataGridViewCell.PaintContentForeground(paintParts))
        {
          if ((cellStyleAlignment & TextFormatFlags.SingleLine) != TextFormatFlags.Default)
            cellStyleAlignment |= TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis;
          TextRenderer.DrawText((IDeviceContext) graphics, text, cellStyle.Font, rectangle3, flag3 ? cellStyle.SelectionForeColor : cellStyle.ForeColor, cellStyleAlignment);
        }
      }
      else
        rectangle1 = DataGridViewUtilities.GetTextBounds(rectangle3, text, cellStyleAlignment, cellStyle);
    }
```

**Sorry for the book!**

**TL;DR USE A SMALL ASS FONT IF YOU WANT TO PACK CHARACTERS INTO HUGE CELLS.**